# Automator application script not working when scheduled from "not on the screen" user

Tags: applescript, automator, calendar, screen, screen-sharing

I have an Automator script (app) that simply does few clicks in an app. This script is launched via a calendar event. The script is scheduled and run from a different admin account than the account that is "physically" opened on the computer screen.

Here is how it goes : when I test the script while connected with Screen Sharing, the script run just fine. But if I leave the Screen Sharing app (the user session should still be running in background), the script return an error when launched by the calendar event **"Watch me do error : (OSStatus error -50)"**. If I do the same, but I schedule the script from the other admin account (the one "physically" opened on the computer screen), it runs fine.

I already set the permissions in Privacy settings to the script.

It seems to be a problem of Automator script execution when runned on a "not on the screen" user account.

Answer (score 0):

## Active User Only

You are correct, the Automator workflow must run within the currently active graphical user session.

Background users, even those with graphical sessions, can not interact with or affect the active graphical session.

### Third Party Tools

Third party tools, such as [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager), are able to help with this task. To do this, the tool must ensure the workflow is launched within the active graphical session. This is typically achieved by using an [assisting process](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/uk-co-dssw-powermanager-pmuser.html) within each user session.

I am an engineer who is involved with Power Manager, so feel free to [get in touch](https://www.dssw.co.uk/support) about how it works.

[image: Power Manager on macOS - Automator daily task]

### Watch Me Do

You should be aware that Automator's *Watch Me Do* task [is fragile](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2014-11-10-automator-watch-me-do/). Where possible, prefer an AppleScript or shell script to improve reliability.